# React state being set back to initial [] when socket.on() is triggered inside useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I am a noob with React functional components and this is my first try with socket-io.

I have a functional component which is an inbox that renders up to ten "alert" rows per page from an `InboxList` array. I am using socket-io so that multiple clients can see in real-time whenever a specific row is clicked (the row turns grey).

The problem is that *most* times the client (observing the row change, not clicking) will have their inbox empty (0 alerts in InboxList) once an alert is clicked.

After some debugging, I found that as soon as the socket.on('alertClicked') is triggered, my inboxList state is empty (instead of having the same 10 alerts I am expecting).

This will cause my `inboxListCopy` inside `greyOutAlert()` to of course be empty.

If anyone has suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Functional component code for context:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Pagination from 'react-responsive-pagination';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../App.css';

let socket;

export default function Inbox() {

    const [token, setToken] = useState(() => {
        return localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    });
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(() => {
        return 1;
    });
    const [alertCount, setAlertCount] = useState(() => {
        return 5;
    });
    const [inboxList, setInboxList] = useState(() => {
        return [];
    });

    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        const connectionOptions = {
            "force new connection" : true,
            "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
            "timeout" : 10000,                  
            "transports" : ["websocket"] 
        }

        socket = io('http://localhost:5000', connectionOptions);
        
        return () => {
            socket.emit('disconnected');
            socket.off();
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchAlertCount();
     },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('alertClicked', (alertId) => {
            greyOutAlert(alertId);
          });
     },[])

    const greyOutAlert = (alertId) => {
        let inboxListCopy = [...inboxList];
        for (let i = 0; i < inboxListCopy.length; i++) {
            if (inboxListCopy[i]._id === alertId) {
                inboxListCopy[i].hasBeenReviewed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        setInboxList(inboxListCopy);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAlerts();
    },[currentPage]);

    const fetchAlertCount = async () => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': token,
            }
        };
        const alertCountResponse = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/alertinbox/totalAlerts', config);
        setAlertCount(alertCountResponse.data.count);
    };

    const fetchAlerts = async () => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': token,
                'page': currentPage
            }
        };
        const alertsResponse = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/alertinbox/', config);
        setInboxList(alertsResponse.data.alerts);
    };

    const handleClick = (alertId, messageType) => {

        socket.emit('clientClickedAlert', {alertId});

        switch (messageType) {
            case '2+ Minutes':
                history.push(`/2plusminutes/${alertId}`, {alertId});
                break;
            case 'SOS':
                history.push(`/sos/${alertId}`, {alertId});
                break;
            case 'Low Battery':
                history.push(`/lowbattery/${alertId}`, {alertId});
                break;
        };
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id='inbox'>
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Alert Type</th>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Timestamp</th>
                            <th>Vehicle</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {inboxList.map(function(alert, index){
                            return(
                                <tr key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(alert._id, alert.messageType)} className={alert.hasBeenReviewed ? 'darken' : 'lighten'}>
                                    <td>{alert.messageType}</td>
                                    <td>{alert.ownerName}</td>
                                    <td>{alert.createdAt}</td>
                                    <td>{alert.vehicle.year + ' ' + alert.vehicle.make + ' ' + alert.vehicle.model}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
            <Pagination
                current={currentPage}
                total={Math.ceil(alertCount/10)}
                onPageChange={setCurrentPage}
                maxWidth={100}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. If you ever need to update the state of something, and that new state depends on the previous state, make sure to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

In my code, I needed the current inboxList state (which is actually the previous state since useEffect() is run after a render) to compute the new inboxList state. To achieve this, I used the optional callback that is part of React's useState hook.

Correct code (useEffect() method updated):

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on('alertClicked', (alertId) => {
        setInboxList(inboxList => {
            let inboxListCopy = [...inboxList];
            for (let i = 0; i < inboxListCopy.length; i++) {
                if (inboxListCopy[i]._id === alertId) {
                    inboxListCopy[i].hasBeenReviewed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return inboxListCopy;
        });
      });
 },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you pass the exact initial state to the useState hook instead of a function like below:

```
const [inboxList, setInboxList] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean code suggestion. I have applied it. It does not fix the issue however, let me know if you any other ideas.